Making an empty array WITHOUT overwriting it
I want to add to an array as I would a list from a for loop but to do so I need to create an empty array first and add to it. Every suggestion I've seen on this site makes it so the old array is overwritten by a new array which seems incredibly silly. The file I am pulling form is 150 x 180,000 data points so lists won't cut it. It seems insane that creating an empty array is some impossible task if making a list is so simple.
This is my code for now but I want to cut the list out of the equation
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils import gc_fraction
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gzip
import numpy as np
with gzip.open("data.fastq.gz",'rt') as input_file:
    sio = SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fastq")
    numdata = []
    for r in sio:
        numdata.append(r.letter_annotations['phred_quality'])
    npa = np.array(numdata)
    plt.boxplot(npa,showfliers = False)
    plt.title("Quality Score Boxplot")
    plt.xlabel("Number of Basepairs")
    plt.ylabel("Number of Reads")
    plt.show()


Appending to a numpy array is not directly supported (not inplace, only by copy) but if you know the final size beforehand you can use numpy.empty to create an array and then fill it with data.

By "array", do you mean a numpy array, like npa in your example? Is the problem that you built the numdata list and then had to create the array? It pretty much has to be this way. Numpy needs to allocate a contiguous chunk of memory so needs the size in advance. And if this is numerical data, numpy is going to use native types in that array, not python objects. Maybe numpy has a native or extension module that reads the fastq file as you want it to.

One solution is to have a script much like the one above that builds the array and then saves it. Its only run when the data file changes. The other would read the faster saved file. Even if the first script has to run each time, its memory is cleared when the script exits.

List designed for easy append. It just adds a pointer to a memory space with grkwth room.  A numpy array cannot grow in place (except in the limited resize method.  Building a list iteratively as you do is normal practice. I suspect your SeqIO parse takes more time..

If you have memory issues, then an alternative method is to read the file twice: first to count the number of records, then allocate an array of the given size, then go through the file again and overwrite the default rows with the values you are reading.

np.array(numdata) needs not only to create a Numpy array but also to parse the content so to check which type to use and then convert all items. This is a bit expensive though SeqIO.parse and the list should be indeed certainly more expensive. You can specify the type of the array for better performance. Note that in some cases, converting the objects to native type can be very expensive regarding the target library. But who know what is supposed to be r.letter_annotations['phred_quality']...  Can you provide a minimal reproducible example (MRE)?

There no such thing as an  'empty array'.  Not np.array([]) nor np.empty(10). And no append method.

Numpy arrays are fixed size and does not allow dynamic resizing like python list. This allows better performance and memory efficiency when performing numerical operations on large datasets.
You can think of this as implementing arrays in low level languages, where you need to predefine arrays.
For your case you can do one of the following:

Option-1: If you know number of elements in advance (or an upper bound), pre-define a numpy array with constant values and fill it in-place.
Option-2: If you do not know number of elements in advance (or upper bound), use lists upto Max size and then append to a numpy array, creating a new copy and deleting old copy.
IMO Option-1 should be able optimal for your use case, sample code below:

    import numpy as np
    import random
    NUM = int(1e+6)
    CONST =0
    arr = np.full(NUM, fill_value=CONST)
    sio = [12]*4 + [43]*4 # sample example
    random.shuffle(sio)
    for i in range(len(sio)):
        arr[i] = sio[i]
    arr = arr[:i+1]

